# How to show response_size and latency in the same chart - Grafana

Tags: prometheus, visualization, grafana

I'm looking for a way to show my metrics in one chart.

Here is the list of my metrics available in Grafana (Data source: Prometheus)

1. `http.server.response.size`
2. `http.server.duration`

I have three metrics per each:

1. `_count`
2. `_sum`
3. `_bucket`

I’m looking for something like:

- X-Axis: `http.server.duration`
- Y-Axis: `http.server.duration`
- Cell Value: count of requests falling into those pairs

Note that the chart will be populated with data available in the selected time range.

Currently, I tried using a Bar Chart, Stat Chart, and other unrelated ones to see if I can find the settings or not, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: 1. Since dots aren't allowed in metric names, I doubt that you provided correct list of metrics in question. 2. If you expect both x and y axis have the same metric as base, you'd better make an effort to explain to goal in more clear terms, because right now it is foggy at best.